# Dealing with dates in Azure DevOps Rest Api

Tags: c#, azure-devops

I am pulling data from work item changes in ADO calling

[https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workItems/{id}/updates?api-version=6.0](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/wit/workItems/%7Bid%7D/updates?api-version=6.0)

Unfortunately I am getting values back that look like

```
"System11111ChangedDate": {
   "oldValue": "2021-09-28T23:59:171111146Z",
   "newValue": "2021-09-28T23:59:2411111677Z"
}
```

and when I take

```
string dt = "2021-09-28T23:59:2411111677Z";
DateTime.Parse(dt, null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);
```

I get

{"String '2021-09-28T23:59:2411111677Z' was not recognized as a valid DateTime."}

I have been messing around with this for a while and still have yet to get it to work.

Any thoughts on how I can do this conversion?

TIA

Answer (score 2):

- The original format for ISO 8601 is ["yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffz"](https://www.progress.com/blogs/understanding-iso-8601-date-and-time-format)
- The string which you have provided is not in a correct format. One (.) dot is missing
  after seconds ( i.e., 24 in your string).
- I have tried using the same given format by adding the extra dot

  ```
   string dt = "2021-09-28T23:59:24.11111677Z";
   DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse(dt, null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);
  ```

Got the below output

```
9/28/2021 11:59:24 PM
```